# How to import user data partition into an Android virtual machine

Tags: virtualization

I have extracted the user data partition from a physical dump of an Android phone. I am searching for a way to import this user data partition into a virtual Android machine, so I can see the contents of the installed apps and the user files as on the phone.

Comment: What's the format of the dump?

Comment: It is a binary UFED physical dump file (.bin)

Comment: `userdata` partition has a filesystem (usually `ext4` or `f2fs`). Simply mount it on Android or any Linux OS, no VM needed.